# I want Age 0 when the date is 0 in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT (GREATEST((YEAR(NOW()) - GREATEST( M.MANUFACTURING_DATE,1900)), 0))
AS AGE,M.MANUFACTURING_DATE FROM table_name M;
```

Above is my mysql query where if i consider MANUFACTURING_DATE =0 then it results Age as 117, i want some solution where if the MANUFACTURING_DATE =0 it should result the Age as 0.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: The above query is showing result of Age as 117 when we consider the MANUFACTURING_DATE =0, but it should show the result as 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a CASE stattement:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN M.MANUFACTURING_DATE=0 THEN 0
        ELSE (GREATEST((YEAR(NOW()) - GREATEST( M.MANUFACTURING_DATE,1900)), 0))
    END
    AS AGE,M.MANUFACTURING_DATE 
FROM table_name M;
```

Comment: you mentioned it correctly, but i want the the query in a single statement. Bit optimized so i can fit it into mysql column condition

Comment: @AishwaryaPatil That **is** a single MySQL statement.

Comment: I mean more optimized query that will run in minimum seconds for a large database